# Debugging What Process Most Consumed Memory on Pods

Tags: kubernetes, memory

I have issue that my application running almost got into its limit at 1 Gi. I've done checking ...

1. the describe pods but nothing events come
2. check htop process through exec but just shows nothing heavy running on background
   [image]
3. check the memory.stat and showing this

[image]

How can I debug whats the process consume most of my memory? I have no many idea about the memory.stat, i've already read the memory.state documentation from [this kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v1/memory.html) and read some stackoverflow but still puzzled. could you please give me a suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

htop is a good approach to find relative memory utilization. we see on the screenshot that inside the pod only apache2 are running. Knowing apache I would guess that it has  big log files.  Can you check by kubectl describe pod if they use [emptyDir volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir).

Another approach is from inside the pod to do `du  -sh /var/log/apache2/*`  (  check the logs location in config file is no logs there) ; if there big file(s), just truncate them by `cat > /var/log/apache2/[name_of_file]` , check memory usage, if the volume is backend by RAM you would see decrease in memory usage.